# How to install dev packages on a Red Hat server that is not connected to internet?

Tags: redhat, yum

I'm a programmer and my Linux knowledge is poor. I have to install rrdtools on a server, and i get some warnings about missing libraries. The server has been set up so that whenever I connect to it via a VPN client, I cannot access the Internet from that server or from the computer I use to access the server. The only way I can bring new files on that server is to put the files on a USB stick and then upload them to the server via pscp.

I normal circumstances, [according to a forum post I've found](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/what-is-the-pkgconfig-file-680416/), if I had Internet access from the server, I would use this command:

`yum install cairo-devel libxml2-devel pango-devel pango libpng-devel freetype freetype-devel libart_lgpl-devel`

I can't do that but I have access to another Red Hat server which has these missing libraries already installed since I was able to install rrdtools on it and I wonder if I can somehow use it to solve my problem.

My question isn't specifically targeted at rrdtools. I expect to encounter this problem further when I'll attempt to install some other software. Is there a way to list the dev packages that yum checks when I run yum install? And a way to find the download location of each package so I can download them manually and try to use something like `yum localupdate` as I've seen [here](http://wiki.contribs.org/Yum_offline_updating)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine the requirements/dependencies of a particular package with `yum deplist packagename`.

That doesn't fully solve your problem, though. Do you have access to a Red Hat DVD? Can you bring that with you?

Another option is to try `yumdownloader` (part of the `yum-utils`) package. Install `yum-utils` on a server with internet access and run `yumdownloader packagename` to download the rpms and depedency packages to your current working directory. You could then take the resulting files to the server that does not have internet access.

If your organization does not provide internet access, it is still possible to use a local repository on your network...