# YUM local install dependencies

Tags: redhat, yum

I have a machine that has no internet access. I am trying to install just the basic MySQL client in order to connect to a MySQL database on another machine that also has no internet access. I can download RPMs onto my personal machine, upload them to the machine with no internet access and install them like so: `yum localinstall name_of_package.rpm`.

Up to now that hasn't been a problem but the MySQL client appears to have a long list of dependencies. I have started installing them one by one but this process is becoming cumbersome.

Is there a way on my personal machine to download a package and all of its dependencies at the same time, upload them all to the machine with no internet access and install them with one command just like I would using *yum* on a machine with internet access? If not I might lose my mind. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install dev packages on a Red Hat server that is not connected to internet?](https://serverfault.com/questions/392208/how-to-install-dev-packages-on-a-red-hat-server-that-is-not-connected-to-interne)

Answer (score 2):

You can download package and it's all dependencies with yum install. For example to download all required rpms into **packages** directory:

```
yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=packages mysql++-devel
```

After all dependencies has been downloaded, you can copy the packages to the target host and install them with

```
yum install *
```